# Как сделать название приложения на нескольких языках? React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Я перевел свое приложение на другой язык, теперь поддерживается два языка.
Но как быть с названием?
Я могу перевести название приложения и тоже менять его как-то?

Comment: Вы о названии что видит пользователь в Google Play  или на экране телефона после установки?

Comment: в телефоне пользователя

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215201/react-native-how-to-localize-app-name

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы сидите с Android Developers Console, то Вы можете выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Выбираете приложение, к которому Вы хотите добавить новое название;
2. Нажимаете на вкладку "Store Listing" (Размещение на Store), а затем на "Add translations" (Добавить переводы);
3. В выпадающем списке выбираете те языки, к которым Вы готовы предоставить локализованный перевод;
4. Оформляете данные к приложению для выбранного Вами языка (в том числе и название).

Comment: А как быть с названием приложения в телефоне пользователя?

Comment: @IIITSTIIIMEEE боюсь, что в данном случае ничего сделать не получится — и иконка, и название уже скачанного приложения одни для всех пользователей, загрузивших его, и с этим ничего не сделаешь